# Information Retrieval: How to combine different word results when using tf-idf?

Tags: search, search-engine, information-retrieval, tf-idf

Let's say I have a user search query which looks like:
`"the happy bunny"`

I have already computed tf-idf and have something like this (following are made up example values) for each document in which I am searching (of coures the idf is always the same):

```
        tf      idf    score
the     0.06    1      0.06 * 1 = 0.06
happy   0.002   20     0.002 * 20 = 0.04
bunny   0.0005  60     0.0005 * 60 = 0.03
```

I have two questions with what to do next.

Firstly, `the` still has the highest score, even though it is adjusted for rarity by idf, still it's not exactly important - do you think I should square the `idf` values to weight in terms of rare words, or would this give bad results? Otherwise I'm worried that `the` is getting equal importance to `happy` and `bunny`, and it should be obvious that `bunny` is the most important word in the search. As long as rare always equals important then it would be always a good idea to weight in terms of rarity, but if that is not always the case then doing so could really mess up the results.

Secondly and more importantly: what is the best/preferred method for combining the scores for each word together to give each document a single score that represents how well it reflects the entire search query? I was thinking of adding them, but it has become apparent that that is going to give higher priority to a document containing 10,000 `happy` but only 1 `bunny` instead of another document with `500` happy and 500 `bunny` (which would be a better match).

Comment: Your values don't make much sense, neither the `tf` nor the `idf` values look right. Are your `tf` values a percentage? That's what it looks like, usually they are just how often the word occurs, so if `the` appeared 20 time it's `tf` value would be 20. How are you calculating your `idf` scores? A word like `the` should be _very_ low (possibly around 4 decimal places, 0.000...).

Comment: As I said in the question: those are made-up example values.

Comment: Does "the" have the highest score in the _actual_ values? Or just in this example?

Comment: For the 3rd time... no, these are example values.

Comment: The IDF values should be fine if they were calculated properly, the [wikipedia page of TFIDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf–idf) has a few variants of how to calculate IDF values. It might be easier if you gave us actual values rather than example values and said how they were calculated in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that you are computing the correct TF-IDF values. As others have pointed they do not look right. TF is relative to specific documents, and we often do not need to compute them for queries (since raw term frequency is almost always 1 in queries). There are different types of TF functions to pick from (check the Wikipedia page on tf-idf, it has a good coverage). Log Normalisation is common and the most efficient scheme, since it saves an extra disk access to get the respective document's total frequency *maxF* that is needed for something like Double Normalisation. When you are dealing with large volumes of documents this can be expensive, especially if you can't bring these into memory. A bit of insight on inverted files can go a long way in understanding some of the underlying complexities. Log normalisation is efficient and is a non-linear function, therefore better than raw frequency.

Once you are certain on your weighting scheme, then you may want to consider a **stop list** to get rid of very common/noisy words. These do not contribute to the rank of documents. It is generally recommended to use a stop list of high frequency, very common words. Do a search and you will find many available, including the one that Lucene uses.

The remaining lies on your ranking strategy and that will depend on your implementation/model. The vector space model (VSM) is simple and readily available with libraries like Lucene, Lemur, etc. VSM computes the Dot product or scalar of the weights of common terms between the query and a document. Term weights are normalised via vector length normalisation (which solves your second question), and the result of applying the model is a value between 0 and 1. This is also justified/interpreted as the Cosine of the angle between two vectors in a planar graph, or the Euclidean distance divided by the Euclidean vector length of two vectors.

One of the earliest comprehensive studies on weighting schemes and ranking with VSM is an [article by Salton (pdf)](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~jbollen/IR04/readings/article1-29-03.pdf) and is a good read if you are interested in Information Retrieval. A bit outdated perhaps (notice how log normalisation is not mentioned in the article).

Your best read I believe is the book **Introduction to Information Retrieval by Christopher Manning**. It will take you through everything that you need to know, from indexing to ranking schemes, etc. A bit lacking on ranking models (does not cover some of the more complex probabilistic approaches).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should reconsider your TF and IDF values, they do not look correct. The TF value is usually just how often the word occurs, so if the word "the" appeared 20 times it's tf value would be 20. A word like "the" should have a  very low IDF value (possibly around 4 decimal places, 0.000...).
   You could use stop word removal if word like the are not necessary, they would be removed rather than just given a low score.
2. A [vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) could be used for this.

Answer (score -1):

can you compute tf-idf  for amalgamated terms? That is, you first generate a sentiment that considers each of its component as equal before treating the sentiment as a single term for which you now compute the tf-idf